# IE doesn't work gradient effect

Tags: html, css, gradient

html

```
<div></div>
```

css

```
div{
    width: 500px; 
    height: 500px; 
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #00f, #fff);
}
```

Does anyone know how to make ie work for gradient effect?

I have also applied `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00f', endColorstr='#fff');`
 but it works differently in ie. You can see this in your test page, copy and paste then see the different between them. IE has deep color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should have for **cross-browser** solution:

```
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,255,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=0 );
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VnRds/4/). Also I recommend using some gradient generator for this. Makes your life a lot easier. For example try c[olorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#0000ff', GradientType='0');
```